# Show/hide shinyTree nodes based on input values and maintain tree state

Tags: r, shiny, shinytree

I would like to filter nodes in a shinyTree based on input values supplied by the user. I have an initial attempt, but the issue is the tree does not maintain state after input, such as open/closed nodes, or selected nodes. For example, in my sample code below, say I have 1-3a and 4-6 expanded, and have value 3 and 5 selected.

[image: Tree state]

If I move the slider to 2, this should remove the 1 entry from 1-3a and 1-3b, I want to keep 1-3a and 4-6 expanded, and values 3-6 checked. However, I'm creating the tree from scratch each time so all state is lost.

[image: Tree state not maintained]

Is there a way to show/hide nodes in shiny tree so that the state is maintained?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(
  grp=rep(c("1-3a","1-3b","4-6"),each=3),
  leaf=c(1:3,1:3,4:6),
  val=c(1:3,1:3,4:6),
)

#' Recursively walks down the columns of a dataframe making nested groups
listTree <- function(dat) {
  if(ncol(dat) > 2) {
    x <- dat %>% nest(data=-1)
    lst <- as.list(x[[2]])
    names(lst) <- x[[1]]
    lst %>% map(listTree)
  } else if(ncol(dat)==2) {
    lst<-as.list(dat[[2]])
    names(lst)<-dat[[1]]
    return(lst)
  } else if(ncol<2) {
    stop('ERROR')
  }
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  p('Filter nodes < selected value'),
  sliderInput("num", "Value",
              min = 1, max = 6, value = 1),
  shinyTree("tree",checkbox=TRUE)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  datr <- reactive({
    dat %>% filter(val >= input$num)
  })
  
  output$tree <- renderTree({listTree(datr())})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ['jsTreeR' package](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR) is similar to the 'shinyTree' package but it allows more possibilities. Here is how one can do to achieve what you want:

```r
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(magrittr)

onrender <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('hideNodes', function(threshold) {",
  "    var tree = $.jstree.reference(el.id);",
  "    var json = tree.get_json(null, {flat: true});",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {",
  "      if(tree.is_leaf(json[i].id) && json[i].text <= threshold) {",
  "        tree.hide_node(json[i].id);",
  "      } else {",
  "        tree.show_node(json[i].id);",
  "      }",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "1-3a",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "1"
      ),
      list(
        text = "2"
      ),
      list(
        text = "3"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "1-3b",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "1"
      ),
      list(
        text = "2"
      ),
      list(
        text = "3"
      )
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "4-6",
    children = list(
      list(
        text = "4"
      ),
      list(
        text = "5"
      ),
      list(
        text = "6"
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      3,
      jstreeOutput("tree")
    ),
    column(
      9,
      sliderInput(
        "threshold",
        label = "Threshold",
        min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["tree"]] <- renderJstree({
    jstree(nodes, checkboxes = TRUE) %>% onRender(onrender)
  })

  observeEvent(input[["threshold"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("hideNodes", input[["threshold"]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]